# Transforming array's element after splitting

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark DF with 1 array column `col1`

```
+--------------------------+
|COL1                      |                                                                                    
|                          |
+---------------------------
|[101:10001:A, 102:10002:B]|
|[201:20001:B, 202:20002:A]|
```

**For all the elements in the array,** I am splitting on **:** and want to pick first part (e.g. 101) if last part of the split is A and otherwise None.

Expected Output:

```
+--------------------------+
|COL2                      |                                                                                    
|                          |
+---------------------------
|[101, None]               |
|[None, 202]               |
```

Code:

```
expr = """
     transform(COL1,
     e -> when(split(e,':')[2] == 'A', split(e, ':')[0]).otherwise(None)
     )
    """
df = df.withColumn("COL2", expr(expr))
```

I got ParseException

```
\nextraneous input '(' expecting {')', ','}(line 3, pos 70)\n\n== SQL ==\n\n         transform(COL1,\n         e -> when(split(e,':')[2] == 'A', split(e, ':')[0]).otherwise(None)\n----------------------------------------------------------------------^^^\n         )\n        \n"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 675, in expr
    return Column(sc._jvm.functions.expr(str))
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 73, in deco
    raise ParseException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `expr()` function, you need to use the SQL syntax, and also you have to rename the variable `expr` which overwrites the API function `expr` and makes it a String. (use `NULL` in the SQL if you don't want the literal string `None`):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

expr1 = """ 
    transform(COL1, 
        e -> IF(split(e,':')[2] = 'A', split(e,':')[0], "None") 
    )
"""       

df.withColumn("COL2", expr(expr1)).show()
```